# How to get SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have purchased a domain from godaddy provider and I launched an application with AWS route 53 service.

My questions:

1. Where to get a SSL certificate? GoDaddy or AWS
2. How to setup SSL certificate?

Please tell me

Comment: You would download the SSL certs from the GoDaddy website.  Then, you would have to import it into your web server.  My experience with GoDaddy was negative, because they don't really offer technical support.  I could not figure out how to import their SSL certs into my Tomcat on AWS.  So, I ended up going with DigiCert instead.

Answer (score 1):

This depends upon your use case or where are you running your application like ECS or EC2 or some static website over s3?

If you are using load balancer on the top of your application then the certificate from AWS is best. you don't need to worry about renewal etc and any other configuration just create load balancer with AWS Certificate Manager.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

CloudFront:

Here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html#cnames-and-https-getting-certificates) how you can configure with CloudFront.

If you to configure directly on your EC2 instance then it's not possible.

> Although you install your website on an Amazon EC2 instance, you
>   cannot directly deploy an ACM Certificate on that instance [source AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-website.html)

Here is the list on which you can AWS certificate.

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon CloudFront
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Amazon API Gateway
- AWS CloudFormation

[Services Integrated with AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html)

You mention that you launched application with Route53 so want to clear one thing

> Amazon Route 53 is a highly available and scalable cloud Domain Name
>   System (DNS) web service.

So Route 53 in DNS and it can be configured with

> Amazon Route 53 effectively connects user requests to infrastructure
>   running in AWS – such as Amazon EC2 instances, Elastic Load Balancing
>   load balancers, or Amazon S3 buckets – and can also be used to route
>   users to infrastructure outside of AWS.

[Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/)

As we are using AWS certificate and we feel good with AWS services, far better than any other service provider in our case.

Let me know if you need further details.